# Is adaptive lasso still unbiased for glm(such as Logistics)?

Tags: logistic, lasso, glmnet

I'm doing something about penalized Logistics regression with adaptive LASSO recently. But I found that the coefficients from Logisitcs+adaptive LASSO is quite different from the normal Logistics regression(after using adaptive LASSO to select variables). So is it still unbiased in generalized linear model framework?

Here's a small demo for this:

```
library(glmnet)
data(BinomialExample)

#get the best ridge est for weights
ridge_model = cv.glmnet(x,y,family="binomial",alpha=0)
best_ridge_coef = as.matrix(coef(ridge_model, s = "lambda.min"))[-1]

ada_model = cv.glmnet(x,y,family="binomial",
                      penalty.factor = 1/abs(best_ridge_coef))

ada_model_coef = coef(ada_model, s = "lambda.min")

#get variables' names after selection
select_name = ada_model_coef@Dimnames[[1]][ada_model_coef@i+1]
myformu = paste("y~",paste(select_name[c(-1)],collapse = "+"),collapse = "")
m = glm(myformu,data=as.data.frame(x),family="binomial")
cbind(ada_model_coef@x,coef(m))

|             | logistic+adaptive LASSO | logistic   |
|-------------|-------------------------|------------|
| (Intercept) | 0.21147889              | 0.3376330  |
| V2          | 0.81107705              | 1.8253424  |
| V3          | -0.62974540             | -1.8883974 |
| V4          | -1.36372345             | -2.7019534 |
| V5          | -0.05068242             | -0.6084139 |
| V6          | -1.17171866             | -2.4895569 |
| V8          | -0.59933151             | -1.4769437 |
| V9          | 0.97380768              | 2.6110472  |
| V10         | -1.69853227             | -3.7953421 |
| V16         | 0.35585867              | 1.3752672  |
| V22         | 0.08099375              | 0.4248433  |
| V23         | 0.31619028              | 1.1179863  |
| V25         | 0.68864092              | 1.7405395  |
| V26         | -0.28087210             | -0.6780907 |
| V28         | 0.16137721              | 0.5577953  |
| V29         | -0.13007464             | -0.6544527 |
```

These two columns above are quite different.

In Zou's paper[2006], adaptive LASSO is unbiased(asy) in linear model framework, which can be seen in this demo:

```
library(glmnet)
data(QuickStartExample)


ridge_model = cv.glmnet(x,y,alpha=0)
best_ridge_coef = as.matrix(coef(ridge_model, s = "lambda.min"))[-1]

ada_model = cv.glmnet(x,y,
                      penalty.factor = 1/abs(best_ridge_coef))

ada_model_coef = coef(ada_model, s = "lambda.min")


select_name = ada_model_coef@Dimnames[[1]][ada_model_coef@i+1]
myformu = paste("y~",paste(select_name[c(-1)],collapse = "+"),collapse = "")
m = lm(myformu,as.data.frame(x))
cbind(ada_model_coef@x,coef(m))

|             | logistic+adaptive LASSO | logistic   |
|-------------|-------------------------|------------|
| (Intercept) | 0.1254233               | 0.1426523  |
| V1          | 1.3870601               | 1.3793234  |
| V3          | 0.7552420               | 0.7790135  |
| V5          | -0.8926079              | -0.9060074 |
| V6          | 0.5688266               | 0.6031976  |
| V8          | 0.3622320               | 0.3981791  |
| V11         | 0.1753393               | 0.2549752  |
| V14         | -1.1145505              | -1.1204391 |
| V20         | -1.1240701              | -1.1556932 |
```

So why the estimators are different in Logistics, does the unbiased property remains? Or just coding mistakes?